# How to copy the contents of two cells dynamically?

Tags: excel, vba

Right now my program works. But, I need to copy another cell that's next to the cell being copied when a match is found. I go through myrange1 and when I find a match in myrange2, I copy the contents from Column A in Sheet1 from whichever cell it's at. I want column B, same cell index, to be copied and pasted as well. My copied data is getting pasted in Column(s) R:S. of Sheet2. Column R is the numbers and S is the data.

```
Sub matchcopy()
    Dim i&
    Dim myrange1 As Range, myrange2 As Range, myrange3 As Range, cell As Range
    ' You can use the Codenames instead of Worksheet("Sheet1") etc.
    Set myrange1 = Sheet1.Range("A1", Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set myrange2 = Sheet2.Range("A1", Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set myrange3 = Sheet2.Range("B1", Sheet2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    Sheet2.Range("R:S") = ""                 ' <~~ clear result columns

    For Each cell In myrange1               ' presumably unique items
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, myrange2, 0)) Then
            'Sheet2.Cells(i, 2).Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 1).Copy

            cell.Copy
            With Sheet2.Range("R50000").End(xlUp)
                 i = i + 1                    ' <~~ counter
                .Offset(1, 0) = i            ' counter i equals .Row - 1
                .Offset(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
            End With

        Else
            'MsgBox "no match is found in range"
        End If
    Next cell

    Sheet2.Columns("R:S").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Call Set_PrintRnag                      
End Sub


Sub Set_PrintRnag()
Dim LstRw As Long
Dim Rng As Range
Dim strDesktop As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
strDesktop = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")

LstRw = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = Sheet2.Range("R1:S" & LstRw)
With Sheet2.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = "&C &B &20 Cohort List Report:" & Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    .CenterFooter = "Page &P of &N"
    .CenterHorizontally = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .RightFooter = ""
End With

Rng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strDesktop & "\CohortList " & " " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `cell.resize(,2).Copy`.

Comment: Thanks SJR. I'm able to copy and paste either A or B, but I cannot get both copy's to paste. It only handles one copy at a time. I need a way to concatenate Column A and B or have it paste both columns either in the same column or two different columns when it does the ".Offset(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats" line

Comment: That's what that line should do - have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, it copied the same data into the column next to it. I have a column with Line numbers, a column with DOB, FN, LN in it and then I need a column next to it that has their address, race, gender etc. in it. Using that line got me my column with numbers, and two columns of DOB, FN and LN.

Comment: I'm confused now. If `cell` is eg A10 then `cell.resize(,2)` is A10:B10. is that what you want to copy?

Comment: One thing I didn't mention, I'm pretty new to VBA, so I apologize. I took out the cell.Copy and used cell.resize( ,2).Copy only and it worked. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Is it possible to get column B of Sheet2 when the match on Sheet2 is found? In other words, if a match is found in row 253 column A of Sheet2, I want to copy the cell at row 253 Column B of Sheet2.

Comment: That would be `cell.offset(0,1)`.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset

You have a cell in column 'A' BUT you want same row in column 'B'.

```
cell.Offset(0,1).value = cell.value
```

Comment: Thank you Zamar for your response. That didn't work for me. I'm still only getting my two original columns pasted in Column(s) "R:S".

Comment: My lists are not the same size. myrange2 is much larger than myrange1. When myrange1 finds a match in myrange2, I want it to copy not only the cell that is matched, but the cell next to it ("B") as well. I created a myrange3, but I'm not even sure if that's a correct approach. I am pretty new to VBA.